# Different question highlighting colors on different favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, design

It would be nice to be able to have different highlighting based on different favorite tags.

An interesting way to do this would be to change the highlight color from the default (`#FFEFC6`) to something more colorful, similar to how the Firefox Colorful Tabs extension works.

I see something like this:

[Colorful Tags http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2061/socolorfultaggedidea.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2061/socolorfultaggedidea.png)
(I also added a 5px left margin to the `.votes` boxes, as it looked a bit odd)

You could further color the tags in the "favorite tags" box on the sidebar based on the color used in the question list to give a visual hint.

Off the top of my head I can think of a few issues (other than *"yuk pastels!"* and *"da colors! they hurts my eyes!"*):

1. how many colors -- what if I have 20 interesting tags?
2. auto color generation could be too costly
3. what happens when a question is tagged with multiple 'interesting' tags?

I'm sure there are others.

Comment: What if you have a question with more than one of your interesting tags?

Comment: ahhhh! my eyes!

Comment: The is no salvation for this insulting image, even with freehand circles!

Comment: @random; remembered that issue after I left the office.. Don't have an answer...

Comment: @Jeff: I'll admit he didn't pick the best colors but the idea should be considered.

Comment: @Lucas... agreed on the colors, ganked them from Colorful Tabs defaults, I'd go for something less eye burning in reality but these were convenient for a demo image.

Comment: I want this feature!

Comment: But wait, this is exactly dup of my yesterday question.  
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104719/choose-the-color-of-highlighting-for-a-certain-tag

Answer (score 9):

I would love this feature. In fact, I came to meta to make just this request.

I have actually stopped adding to my interesting tags because the new ones I want drown out the old ones.

Comment: I know it's just a bit offtopic, but do you think you could send me one invitation to careers when your issue is resolved (if you can gimme one?)

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is this script which colors the tags:

[Bold and colorful area tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/2566/bold-and-colorful-area-tags)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would love this feature. People carrying about their eyes - do not worry. It will be user-based choice, it means you won't see anybody's else colors :)

Comment: glad you like my yesterday reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Let's make it really cool ;)

[image]

Although more distinction would be preferred indeed, I doubt that any visual addition will fit elegantly within the site's style.

Comment: -1: needs more blink!

Comment: @NGLN How did you create gif from browser?

Comment: @genesis With Animation Shop Pro.