# Choose the color of highlighting for a certain tag

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different question highlighting colors on different favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/different-question-highlighting-colors-on-different-favorite-tags)

Maybe this already has been discussed, so I gonna be downvoted to death pretty fast :) but nevertheless I want to ask for this feature. As we all know, we can set up a list of favorite tasks, and questions, which contain that tags will be highlighted. Here is a screenshot for those who do not have favorite tags:
[image: screenshot]

Sometimes I'm really missing the ability to set a color of highlighting for a specific tag. I mean, yes, we can always read the tag itself, but actually the highlighting exists **exactly** because recognizing color is faster than reading.

**UPD:** @doncherry came up in the comment with an excellent question - what if the question contains few favorite tags? Feel free to discuss exact implementation also. I see few possible options here:

- Color for first or for the last tag encountered.
- Color in a special color, which actually means - this is  just a favorite tag, no matter what. So, it is just a default color.
- Try to invent UI scheme to involve several colors. Say, sort of thin stripe above the "main color" or something else.

@genesis-φ (yet, in some ironical way :) pointed out another issue  -  preset colors should be thoroughly tested. Only soft, pastel colors should be used, or we get to motley quilt of posts.

Comment: Nice idea. What's gonna happen if a question is tagged with two or more of your favorite tags?

Comment: @doncherry, I think we shouldn't go to far here - we can choose some simple rule. Say, always color to the last tag encountered, or the first one. If we want to make things a bit more complicated we can provide an ability to reorder favourite tasks. But I not sure for that. Just simple rule can be enough to make me happy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes please. It can look like

[image]
<sub>(source: [phpcode.eu](http://phpcode.eu/images/1314882493.png))</sub>

and it is a lot better :)

Comment: Certainly, the pallette should contain preset of pastel, soft colors. Why, for example, you haven't colored everyting marooon, orange and brown? )))) Besides, it is 100%percents up to you, whether to choose different colors or not, this is the layout only you can see.