# Is it appropriate to ask questions of "temporary nature" here?

Tags: discussion

Often I try to find something I saw once, and fail.

For example, just a moment ago I was looking for two things (I'm mentioning this because maybe someone will remember something about them)
- how to view only questions that have some of the interesting tags in them, and hide all others
- and how to color questions in different colors, depending on the tag (browser extension)

As I said, both topics were dealt with once, but I cannot find them. In situations such as this, where should a person go with his question? Post it here in this form? Chat?

Answer (score 1):

If you see something that you like make a it a favorite - click on the star next to the question.

It will then be available to you in your favorites.

Comment: Of course. But for that one has to be interested in it, at the time. I often pass along questions, that I find interest in later.

Comment: @ldigas - So your question is really about forecasting your future interests ;)

Comment: Cute ;) _______

Answer (score 1):

Your Search-Fu is weak!

- Searchterm: question color tags

  - First result: [Choose the color of highlighting for a certain tag [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104719/choose-the-color-of-highlighting-for-a-certain-tag)
  - Duplicate of: [Different question highlighting colors on different favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/different-question-highlighting-colors-on-different-favorite-tags)
- Searchterm: questio  hide tags ... I'm not kidding, that typo works!

  - First result (though, not temporary): [Hide questions with a specific tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106640/hide-questions-with-a-specific-tag)

If you think you already saw it, search again...and again...and again...always change the wording. If you've searched to no avail, then you can ask it. Otherwise, if the question is still there, someone will find it and close your question as duplicate. If it isn't there anymore, well, good thing you asked!

Comment: Darn, my british english. "colour" instead of "color" matches quite different results :/ I don't mind people closing my q's as duplicates :)

Comment: Btw, I don't see the answer to coloring the question with specific tags in there; only the screenshot.

Comment: How do I view only questions which have tags I'm interested, and hide all others? The proposed solution does not seem to work.

Comment: @ldigas: There's a preference tab in your account page with that option.

Comment: Ugh, let me review. I have (for the purpose of this example) 5 tags I'm interested in, and 30 tags I'm not. I've come to the conclusion that I only follow the 5 tags mentioned. I don't wish to single handedly enter every other tag I'm not interested in. How do I hide all the questions, yet leaving visible the ones that contain at least one of the tags I'm interested in? Currently I have the "hide" option checked, but that doesn't do anything helpful. If I put "*" in the ignored tags box, I no longer see the questions that contain at least one of the "interesting" tags.